# modify visual basic regular expression to work in java

Tags: java, regex, vb.net

i want to use java regex for capture certain pattern of word from text box.i have vb regex for that.but it's not valid in java.i want to know how should it modify for java.

this is my vb reqex

```
class\s+([^\s]+)[\s\r\n{]
```

i did same in java this way.but it always say no mathes found but vb did.

this is java code

```
String text=jTextArea2.getText();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)class\\s+(\\S+)[\\s{]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
String found =matcher.group(1);
System.out.print(found);
```

Comment: it seems a polite regex to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java strings you need to escape the backslashes, so `\s` becomes `\\s`. Now let's improve your regex a bit:

- Let's add the `i` modifier to match case insensitive `(?i)`
- `[^\\s]+` is the same as `\\S+`
- `\\s` also includes newlines so `[\\s\\r\\n{]` becomes `[\\s{]`

Your final regex may look like: `(?i)class\\s+(\\S+)[\\s{]`.

Comment: @user3588824 Please learn to read the manual or do some research. Here's how you [use the code](http://ideone.com/UdNnK0).

Answer (score 0):

The regex will work great, the only thing that you must do is escape the `\` to `\\` for Java strings.